# Why is this SQL query not seem to be failing but actually failing?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am adding a logger class to my web server and noticed that my logs are not being inserted although the query does not return a failure value.

This is my database handler class's query executer function:

```
//_mysql = MYSQL*
bool DatabaseConnection::query(const std::string &query) const {
    return _mysql && 0 == mysql_real_query(_mysql, query.c_str(), query.length());
}
```

And this is the SQL query I attempted to execute:

```
insert into user_logs (id, action, when) value (1, 2, 1615856674);
```

When the C++ program executed this query it returned success however did not actually insert the row. So, I tried to manually execute it via a client and the query failed by telling me to wrap `when` with `` ` ``.

After that the query worked as expected both in the client's console and in the C++ program.

I wonder why did it not fail in the C++ program?

Comment: Looking at the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-query.html it might be getting confused by the terminating `;` _"...Normally, the string must consist of a single SQL statement without a terminating semicolon..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten To be honest, I didn't know that and was always putting a semicolon at the end whether it was a single or multiple statement. So, thank you for this ^^. However, in both times I used a semicolon at the end and the only difference was the `s wrapping the 'when'.

Comment: If `mysql_real_query()` returns 0, but does not actually execute the query, that sounds like a bug that should be reported. What does [`mysql_affected_rows()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) return?

Comment: Is [when](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) a reserved word in mysql?  The linked page has it listed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau with `s 1 - as expected -, and otherwise 18446744073709551615. I guess it's ULLONG_MAX. Maybe I also need to check for that for failure?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But if that's the problem, it should return an error code.

Comment: @themql `mysql_affected_rows()` returns `(uint64_t)-1` on failure. Per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html): "*An integer greater than zero indicates the number of rows affected or retrieved. Zero indicates that no records were updated for an UPDATE statement, no rows matched the WHERE clause in the query or that no query has yet been executed. **-1 indicates that the query returned an error** or that, for a SELECT query, mysql_affected_rows() was called prior to calling mysql_store_result()...*"

Comment: @themql "*... Because mysql_affected_rows() returns an unsigned value, you can check for -1 by comparing the return value to (uint64_t)-1 (or to (uint64_t)~0, which is equivalent).*

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, I see, thanks. I was expecting a failure in the mysql_real_query() response so never thought of checking this.

Comment: @themql I don't see any [error codes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/client-error-reference.html) defined for `mysql_real_query()` for bad SQL syntax.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Uh, not sure if you meant my wrapper class but if that's the case I'm still on early stages of the development and will expand the class to be more informative.

Comment: @themql No, I meant the error code that `mysql_real_query()` returns on failure. I don't use mySQL myself, and I don't know what the behavior of `mysql_real_query()` is expected to be when passed a bad SQL query, since there does not appear to be an error code defined to report that condition.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, my bad. Yeah, it returns 0. But when I execute it in a MySQL Client program it fails for bad syntax. That's something confuses me as well. Normally, it returns something other than 0 to tell me something is wrong and it cannot execute the statement successfully.

Comment: @themql nevermind, I found the error code after all: [`ER_SYNTAX_ERROR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_syntax_error) (1149).

Comment: I'm still not convinced that the problem is not the `when`.  It sure looks suspicious, given that the page I linked to lists it as a keyword in mysql, and possibly the reason why you have to jump through hoops putting quotes around it for the query to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The problem in the SQL statement was about when's quotation for the reason you said - it is a keyword. Still, if the query failed, it shouldn't have returned 0 indicating a successful execution of the query. The very same query failed in a MySQL client's console for not putting quotes, although both C++ program and the client were connected to the same database instance; most likely indicating a bug in the connector library I've used in the C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

*"When the C++ program executed this query it returned success however did not actually insert the row."*

It depdens on the client your C++ program is using. It might have simply swallowed the exeption and gives you the impression that it succeeded while it's not.  To figure out why, you will need to dig into the C++ mysql client's source code.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to execute queries using C++ code, try removing the terminating semicolon `;`.

As an example, will not work. `std::str query = "select * from table;";` But,
`std::str query = "select * from table";` will work.